# Move custom block Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, xml

I have added a custom block to the order information page.

But I would like to move it under account information.
How would I go on about doing this?

[image: custom-block]
view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="order_info">
        <block class="Vender\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Custom" name="sales_order_view_custom" template="order/view/custom.phtml" />
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just override the template

`vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/info.phtml`

by copying it under your custom theme and remove the call of the child blocks

```
  <?php echo $block->getChildHtml(); ?>
```

before the closing of the

```
<div class="admin__page-section-item order-account-information">
```